# Add List Partitions to un-partitioned Oracle Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Am I able to add list partitions to an un-partitioned oracle table? I have seen range partitions added in other examples online, but not list partitions. If I am able to add list partitions to an existing non-partitioned oracle table, are there some requirements that must be met to do so?

I tried

```
alter table t1 MODIFY
PARTITION  BY LIST (c1)
( PARTITION c1a VALUES ('c1a'),
       PARTITION c1b VALUES ('c1b'),
       PARTITION c1c VALUES ('c1c'))
```

But get:
ORA-14006;invalid partition name

Comment: What is the Oracle version that you are using, I believe this is available from Oracle e 12.2c onwards

Comment: I am using version 11.2.0.3.0. If I cannot add partitions to this existing table, can I take every aspect in this table and create a new table with the list partitions. This table has a lot of columns so it would be nice if I did not have to define the data types for every column

Comment: Hi, you can use the CTAS and create the table structure, CREATE table NEW_PARTITION_TAB   PARTITION BY LIST .....  as select * from old_tab where 1=0;